# Count the number of occurrences from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Be a DataFrame in pandas of this format:

| ID | time | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 81219 | blue |
| 0 | 32323 | green |
| 1 | 423 | red |
| 1 | 4232 | blue |
| 1 | 42424 | red |
| 2 | 42422 | blue |

I simply want to create a DataFrame like the following by counting the number of times each row is output in the previous DataFrame.

| ID | number_appears |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've added the `group-by` tag, which is almost certainly what you're looking for ;)

Comment: `groupby` here will be slower: use `df["ID"].value_counts(sort=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('ID').count()
```